# Slider image issue in wordpress

Tags: images

I am developing a wordpress site using the theme **Enlighten**. For other theme i had used page concept for adding sliders and other contents. But accoding to the documentation provided by the enlighten theme, they are using post concept to add sliders and other contents.

Here  i am attaching the documentation link:

http://doc.accesspressthemes.com/enlighten-documentation/#!/news_slide_section_setting

I have successfully added slider to my website. but i am facing an issue that my slider images are coming as seperate posts. I have attached a screen shot below;
[image: Screenshots]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Setting** --> **Reading Setting**

Change **front page** display as **static page**

Select the *static page*

**Save** the page